# React scrolling missing background color

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a react application. This seems like more of a css issue though. I have set the height in my style to "100vh" but that only covers what is initially viewable with my background color. As I add more components to the page, it requires me to scroll down and the background color is now white. I would like to be able to dynamically adjust the area in which the background color covers. What css could I use to do this? I am new to web development so being specific could help.

Comment: Can you show the HTML in which this happens? You say, "the area", but that is too vague. Is it a specific HTML element, such as a div? In that case, leaving out the `height` property will do the trick. With the height not set, the element will be as high as its contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share your code it will help to give more accurate answer but generally try to add

to your CSS code:

```
    background-size : cover;
```

it should adjust the background size to the actual size of the DOM element.

if any additional clarifications are required I will be happy to assist